# Determine Continuous Streak using MySQL

Tags: mysql

For example:

```
GAME_ID   GOALIEID    TEAMID    TEAMSHOTNUM  OVERALLSHOT   SCORED
2001        57          11            1            1          Y
2001        41          22            1            2          N
2001        57          11            2            3          N
2001        41          22            2            4          N
2001        57          11            3            5          N
2001        41          22            3            6          Y
2001        57          11            4            7          N
2001        41          22            4            8          Y
```

Based on this simple example: How can I query for the most consecutive "Saves" which would be "N" by a "GoalieID" now imagine my data has multiple games to look through but for simplicity I only have the one game here.

My result I would hope to look like this:

```
GAME_ID     GOALIEID     STREAK
  2001        57           3
```

This would show that "GOALIEID" #57 made 3 consecutive saves in the shootout showing that the highest consecutive streak of saves was in fact 3. Note remember this will be across thousands of games. But i made it simple here with just 1 game.

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: Well I have been doing my queries through PopSQL and it links to the MySQL Workbench 8.0 Database where I initially uploaded my data from excel

Comment: Please tell **server** version. Reason I am asking this is that depending on the server version, solution can become less verbose.

Comment: I'm not sure where I would find that out I downloaded the public MySQL 8.0 Workbench

Comment: Try to figure out. It is not that difficult. Google. Anyways I am preparing a general solution which shall work for all the versions. So wait for it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- An approach using [Session Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) can be used. It will work for all `GAME_ID` and `GOALIEID` combinations.
- In order to use Session variables properly, we first need to order our dataset. So in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we sort our data at multiple levels by `GAME_ID`, `GOALIEID`, and `OVERALLSHOT`; since a unique Streak is defined for a Goalie in a particular Game.
- Now, we use this ordered data-set to determine streak. We utilize [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function for our conditional logic. Logic here is that if we encounter a Goal (`SCORED = 'Y'`), we set the Streak number to **0** (as it has been broken); else (Goal is saved) if the previous `GAME_ID` and `GOALIEID` are same as current, we **increment** our Streak number; otherwise set the Streak number to **1**
- Now, we simply use this dataset again as a Derived Table, and `Group By` on `GAME_ID` and `GOALIEID`, and use [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group.html) function to determine the maximum Streak number for a particular Game and Goalie.

You can also refer this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) explaining how session variables are used to calculate row number.

Try the following code to get Maximum Streak:

```
SELECT 
  dt.GAME_ID, 
  dt.GOALIEID, 
  MAX(dt.STREAK) AS STREAK 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    @streak := IF(t1.SCORED = 'Y', 
                  0, 
                  IF(@gameid = t1.GAME_ID AND 
                     @goalieid = t1.GOALIEID, 
                     @streak + 1, 
                     1)
                 ) AS STREAK, 
    @gameid := t1.GAME_ID AS GAME_ID, 
    @goalieid := t1.GOALIEID AS GOALIEID 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      GAME_ID, 
      GOALIEID, 
      SCORED 
    FROM your_table 
    ORDER BY GAME_ID, GOALIEID, OVERALLSHOT ) AS t1 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @gameid := 0, 
                     @goalieid := 0, 
                     @streak := 0) AS init_params 
) AS dt 
GROUP BY dt.GAME_ID, dt.GOALIEID
```

---

**[Rextester DEMO](https://rextester.com/CJQTIF39070)**

**Output:**

[image: Rextester Demo Output]